# How do I get a specific value from xml in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

My problem is a bit typical and I am very new to working with xml. Please view the following code:

```
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load(myxml);

    Response.Write("<p><strong>First Result</strong><br/>");

    for (int nodeCount = 0; nodeCount < xDoc.ChildNodes.Count; nodeCount++)
    {
        Response.Write(xDoc.ChildNodes[nodeCount].Name + ":");
        Response.Write(xDoc.ChildNodes[nodeCount].InnerXml + "<br/>");
    }

    Response.Write("</p>");
```

.. and the output I get in the aspx page is as follows:

```
First Result
xml:
Response:OK122.160.37.198ININDIAWEST BENGALKOLKATA70015522.569788.3697+05:30
```

I want the values 'WEST BENGAL' and 'KOLKATA' from it. I am not being able to read/write this in xml format so that I can grab the required nodes and their values. How to do that?

Comment: Can we see your XML content?

Comment: can you show us the input xml?

Comment: As you can see, the input xml will coming from the url (see my code above). The output is what I have pasted, but in string format. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath to search the XML. use your "xDoc" variable

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(XmlReader(xDoc));
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
XPathExpression exprName = nav.Compile(xPathName);
XPathNodeIterator iteratorName = nav.Select(exprName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Descendants()` function on the `XDocument` itself, consider this example:

(Note - have made assumptions about how your data looks)

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
static void Main()
{
   var xml = "<Data><ININDIA>WEST BENGAL</ININDIA><ININDIA>KOLKATA</ININDIA></Data>";
   var xd = XDocument.Parse(xml);
   //get all `XElement` objects with the name "ININDIA"
   foreach (var e in xd.Root.Descendants()
        .Where(e=>e.Name.LocalName=="ININDIA"))
    {
      Console.WriteLine(e.Value);
    }
}
```

will produce

```
WEST BENGAL
KOLKATA
```

Comment: Your solution looks good, sir, but surprisingly I am not being able to call the `System.Xml.Linq` in my code-behind, even after adding reference to it! I am using .NET F/W 3.5. Should I get that dll and place it to the **bin** folder? That's horrible!

Comment: @leodeep there shouldn't be any need, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Firstly, the namspace is not coming by autocomplete. Secondly,`XDocument` is not getting recognized.

Comment: try also adding  `using System.Xml`